# Install GIT on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, git

I was trying to install Git on my Ubuntu `18.04` version with the command

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

But I was recieving the below shown error. How can I fix this one?
[image]

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:   
git : Depends: git-man (< 1:2.17.0-.) but 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.7 is to be installed
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text outputs, instead, copy/paste the ouput into the question.

Comment: _Mikewhatever_ is right. Highlight text, then Ctrl-Shift-C to copy the text. Return here, click [edit], and paste that text into your question.

Comment: @K7AAY mikewhatever, I have added the error console in the queston as quoted test aswell, not just the image. Any way my isse was resolved by the solution mentioned in N0rbert's comment

Answer (score 1):

Please run `apt-get update` , before  running your `apt-get install` command .